The required antiforgery header value "RequestVerificationToken" is not present
I'm trying to implement CSRF between a Next.js frontend and a .NET backend API.
First, the frontend app gets a CSRF token from the API. The API returns a cookie with the antiforgery token.
antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(httpContext);

Here's the antiforgery config in the .NET API:
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    })

...

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAntiforgery();

Then, the frontend app is sending another request to the API that is sending along the antiforgery cookie. This is actually happening when I check developer tools in the browser. So far so good.
Howver, when I validate the antiforgery token in the .NET API, an exception is thrown.
await this.antiForgery.ValidateRequestAsync(httpContext);

Exception:
The required antiforgery header value "RequestVerificationToken" is not present

Should I have a request header RequestVerificationToken if I already send an antiforgery cookie? If so, where do I get the value from?
Should I change the AddAntiforgery options in some way?


Should I have a request header RequestVerificationToken if I already send an antiforgery cookie? If so, where do I get the value from? Should I change the AddAntiforgery options in some way?

Based on my testing, we need use both cookie and set the header according to your program.cs settings.
For example, you could modify your api to also return a token.
app.MapGet("/gettoken", (HttpContext context, IAntiforgery antiforgery) =>
{
    var token = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
    return Results.Content(token.RequestToken );
});

Then you need set the token inside the request header RequestVerificationToken as the exeption said.
Besides, you could also set the header name by using below codes:
...
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAntiforgery();
...

This makes the application will check the request header X-XSRF-TOKEN instead of the RequestVerificationToken.

Got it working now exactly like you describe.
